# How can I add two bytes in Assembly if the sum of these two bytes exceeds a byte?

Tags: assembly, x86, byte, nasm

I am studying the Assembly language in collage and I am pretty sure I don't understand anything, especially since the classes are online.

This is probably a very simple question, but still, I don't know the answer. Suppose I want to add two numbers that I stored as bytes `a = 255` and `b = 255`. I don't think this works if we do this:

```
segment data use32 class=data
    a db 255
    b db 255

segment code use32 class=code
    start:
    
        mov al, [a]
        add al, [b]
```

Since the sum is `510`, which cannot be stored in `AL` because `AL` is a 1 byte sized register, right? I tried this with NASM (which I have close to no clue as to how to use it) and I don't *think* I got the right answer. The EAX register looks like this at the end `0019FFFE`, and 510 in hexa is `1FE` so I suppose I should see a `1FE` somewhere, which we don't!

So I guess that's not the right way. Then I tought that maybe I can use `AX` for the addition somehow. So I did something like this:

```
segment data use32 class=data
    a db 255
    b db 255

segment code use32 class=code
    start:

        mov ax, word 0
        mov al, [a]
        add al, [b]
```

I tought that if we have initialized `AX` as 0 and then added something to `AL` that would result in a value that would exceed a byte, the result will propagate through `AX`, and we'd get the right answer. But I got `001900FE` at the end, so again there's no trace of a `1FE`.

So how should I add these two values? I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, but I'm really confused. I retained close to nothing from class and the sources on the internet are very scarce when regarding Assembly, so I didn't really find the answer to my question online.

Comment: You add to `al`, which is only the lowest 8 bits of `eax`. The upper bits are unaffected by the instruction. Yes, this is a terrible misfeature of x86 that nobody today wants, and it traces its origin back to the 8-bit predecessors of x86 (8008/8080/8085), because even then Intel was beholden to compatibility for their brand-new processor design. If you want widening add, you can first load into a register and then add the whole (16- or 32-bit) register.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're not already using the maximum size that the processor handles, then you can go up a size.

Do the addition in 16-bits instead.  The processors generally don't support adding 8-bit values into a 16-bit answer, but you can promote the 8-bit values to 16-bits then do 16-bit addition.

To extend to 16-bits, you can load a value into `al`, then clear `ah`, so now `ax` holds a 16-bit value.  Do the same in bl/bh/bx or cl/ch/cx, and you can then add the two 16-bit values together.  This is assuming your inputs are unsigned bytes.  (If they were signed bytes, you'd use sign extension operations to promote to 16 bits.)  You can also clear `ax` first, then load into `al`, and you'll have a 16-bit zero extended value in `ax`.

If you are trying to do the same, but you're already using the maximum size for the processor, say with 32-bit, you would check the carry flag after the addition, which would tell you if the addition either overflowed or didn't (which means it fits in 32 bits).

By the way the carry flag is also set by doing 8-bit addition, so you can also check that to see if the result is larger than 8 bits.

As a rule, adding two n-bit values produces an n+1 bit answer, and, multiplying two n-bit values produces an 2n-bit answer.  On the x86, the carry flag is used as that extra bit in addition, and the multiply instructions are geared to providing larger answers.

Comment: The OP mentions EAX; that means they can simply `movzx eax, byte [a]` / `movzx ecx, byte [b]` instead of messing around with partial registers, on a 386-compatible CPU.

Comment: @ErikEidt That cleared a lot of my confusions, thanks a lot. You said "You can also clear ax first, then load into al, and you'll have a 16-bit zero extended value in ax.". Are we clearing ax (so we set it to 0) to empty it from the garbage values that may be in memory before the program starts? Did I get that right?

Comment: Yes, normally we don't clear the registers after using them, so we should think of them as having unknown values.  Normally, this is not an issue as we simply load the register with new values, but zero extension needs some zeros.  Also, as @PeterCordes has mentioned, you can promote them all the way to 32 bits, and there is a single instruction to load and zero extend at the same time.

Comment: @ErikEidt Just one more confusion, if you don't mind answering. You said "If you are trying to do the same, but you're already using ..... which would tell you if the addition either overflowed or didn't (which means it fits in 32 bits)." What if i get overflow? Is there a way to work around and find the actual sum, if we already use the largest, registers like EAX and EBX. Also, Say I clear AX and BX, fill in AL and BL with 8-bit values and then sum AX and BX. If the sum exceeds 8 bits, will the carry flag still get set? Even If I do addition using the 16 bits registers AX and BX?

Comment: The carry bit is the 33rd bit. With a 33 bit answer for 32-bit addition, there is no potential for overflow.  It is only when we try to discard the 33rd bit, and keep just the low 32 bits that there is the potential for overflow, and the carry flag will tell us when the real numeric value requires the 33rd bit (to be 1) which also means that discarding that high order 33rd 1-bit will cause overflow since the remaining numeric value in 32-bits will change / will not be correct.